# Android RelativeLayout Issue with different screen dimentions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testing.testinglibraryapps.Main2Activity">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I divide Android screen into two parts. i.e one Relative layout should be on 3/4 part of screen and other should be of 1/4

What properties should I set here to achieve my desired layout

Comment: why not use `Linear Layout` as parent and give it a `weight sum`

Comment: can you share your UI example then i can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:weightSum="4"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        >

        <!--Other Views Here-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        >

        <!--Other Views Here-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:weightSum="4"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"

        >



    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        >



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: amazingly. Almost same as mine.